# DynamoDB Transaction Write with other Data Stores

Tags: c#, .net, redis, transactions, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create a certain set of processes to be transactional. DynamoDB's **TransactWriteItems** are only transactional for writing into the Dynamo table. I am trying to Write into DynamoDB as well as update my Redis Cache for the new data that is written. Is there a way to make these set of processes transactional in .NET C#? If there is a way to manually trigger Dynamo to complete the transaction after Redis has completed, that'll be great as well.

Pseudocode:

```
    // Write to DynamoDB
    // dynamoDBClient.PutItemAsync(...);

    // Write to Redis
    // redisClient.StringSetAsync(...);

    // If Redis fails, rollback DynamoDB write
    // If any exception happens, rollback all changes
    // If no exceptions occur, commit all changes
```

Comment: Did you see DAX (https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/dax/)? It might be easier to manage and provide better performance.